# is it possible to find if message is unread using java mail API?

Tags: java

I was using java mail to read Gmail as following -

```
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "mail", "password");

Folder folder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
```

Now I wan to find out if message is unread, but could not find any API.
I want to do something like -

```
 for(Message message:messages) {

    if(message.isUnread) {
    // Do Something here
    }
 }
```

While there is no such API - isUnred.

Comment: Or better if I could get collection of all unread messages, instead of trying to check with every message if it is unread....

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you tried Message.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Flags.Flag.html#SEEN

> This message is seen. This flag is implicitly set by the implementation when the this Message's content is returned to the client in some form

it's been a while since I used JavaMail, but I think that does what you want

Comment: how do i query the messages to get only those that are unread?

Comment: This flag work for Gmail and yahoo emails, but not Hotmail email. Is anybody face this problem or solve this issue?

Comment: I have found the reason of why this flag not working for Hotmail, because Hotmail not working with "imap" so I have used "pop3" for reading emails. POP not supported this parameter.

Comment: Just an update, it doesn't seem like the hyperlink is working anymore. Still a good answer, though :)