# Finding a specific unread mail from list of mails using Javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

MY approach is -

1. Get the total mail list -

   ```
   List<Message> totalMessageList = Arrays
               .asList(folder.getMessages());
   ```
2. Create a list out of this which has only unread mails. (I had to do this coz I could not find a any direct API to get list of new mails. One question which helped in finding whether a message is unread or not was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6898178/is-it-possible-to-find-if-message-is-unread-using-java-mail-api/6898222#6898222))

   ```
   List<Message> unreadMessageList = new ArrayList<Message>();
   ```

   For sake of brevity I have not posted entire logic of building the list of unread mail from list of total mails.
3. Iterate through the list of unread mails > Check if any mail has desired subject then read content of mail > If no such mail found then throw IllegalStateExcepton

Now my question is - Could I improve on this approach?

Comment: Depending on your application, it may seem odd that an empty mailbox is in an illegal state.

Comment: I must have mentioned that I am using Gmail

Comment: Nop, its not empty mail box, It is not having got a new desired mail which I was using to trigger IllegalStateException. If not this then what could be better exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use

```
Folder.search(SearchTerm): Message[]
```

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/Folder.html#search%28javax.mail.search.SearchTerm%29

with the relevant SearchTerm, e.g. FlagTerm for the unread flag

http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/javax/mail/search/FlagTerm.html

Quick search on Google found this

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Email/Searchthegivenfolderformessagesmatchingthegivencriteria.htm

which might be useful, but I haven't tried it

Comment: Just realized, how much code I was writing for simplest of task. Thanks

Comment: A pleasure, it has been a while since I used it, but I was impressed by how easy javax.mail made most of the things I wanted to do.